# flee at your presence seven ways

Tags: deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 28:7 (NASB)

> “The Lord will cause your enemies who rise up against you to be defeated by you; they will go out against you one way and will **flee at your presence seven ways**.

What does it mean to "flee at your presence seven ways"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"seven" of anything is quintessential Hebrew idiom for something complete.  In this case, seven is a literary contrast to "one" earlier in the save verse of Deut 28:7.  Thus, while an enemy army might attack the Israelites from one direction, they will be defeated and scatter in seven directions - that in in complete disarray.

Note the comments of Ellicott:

> (7) And flee before thee seven ways.—“So is the custom of them that
> are terrified, to flee, scattering in every direction” (Rashi). See
> the story of the flight of the Midianites (Judges 7:21-22), and of the
> Syrians (2Kings 7:7).

Keil and Delitzsch Biblical Commentary on the Old Testament -

> so that they shall come out against thee by one way, and flee from
> thee by seven ways, i.e., in wild dispersion (cf. Leviticus 26:7-8).

Comment: Oh got it. They'd "flee perfectly"!

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - perfectly, or possibly better, "completely"